# give input on VS. give input into

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, verbs

The U.S Department of Education tries to ensure that school playgrounds do not violate any of the engineering standards set for child safety, but it doesn't **give input on** public parks.

I am wondering which one of the following is more more sufficient:

input on

input into

Thanks in advance

Comment: Context? nima, we *love* context! Please tell us where the example comes from or what you want to express if the text is yours. We want to give the best answers, but hate guessing.

Comment: Thanks. But, it is all that I have. I have no longer context. This is taken from the book Inside Reading 3

Comment: The book has not mentioned any more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Give input into" and "give input on" have different meanings. To **give input into** something is to provide information or resources. I would give input to a computer program, or perhaps give input to a machine.

To **give input on** something is to offer suggestions or opinions about the topic. In your example, the U.S Department of Education has opted *not* to offer suggestions about public parks, only school playgrounds. The input here isn't for the literal object (e.g., parks or playgrounds), but rather for a discussion *about* the object.